# How to show up DeleteButton in react-admin? And not only the last stuff loading from database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, material-ui, react-admin

I started using javascript and React for a small project based on REST. So I tried to show some datas from my database in a browser, but only the last Product shows up 7 times (only 7 products are in the database). And additionally the `DeleteButton` don't want to show up, and when I try to have a look on a product from web browser (through `EditButton`), it says *Element does not exist*. This last should be because it want to redirect http://localhost:5000/orders/undefined. So maybe it can't get the ID of a product?
Here is the code for the `DeleteButton` part:

```
import React from 'react';
import {List, Datagrid, TextField, NumberField, ImageField, EditButton, DeleteButton} from 'react-admin';

const ProductList = (props) => {
    return <List {...props}>
            <Datagrid>
                <TextField label = 'ID' source = '_id' />
                <TextField source = 'title' />
                <NumberField source = 'year' />
                <TextField source = 'author' />
                <ImageField source = 'productImage' />
                <EditButton basePath = '/products' />
                <DeleteButton basePath = '/products' />
            </Datagrid>
        </List>
};

export default ProductList;
```

Thanks,

Comment: How you retrieve the data? I mean, in their example, react-admin is using a [data provider](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-admin-f38gy?file=/src/App.js:338-418) Maybe there is something with your provider..

Comment: It's probably a problem with your API or your dataProvider. It should return a unique id for each record as a response to getList.

Comment: The problem was the npm package or whatever we call it. I had to reinstall it, and also used an other data provider which can use custom ID name (not only id).